# Where did I go on this trip?

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

I went on a trip yesterday. However I can't quite remember where I went. All I have is my diary entry for yesterday, but I'm struggling to make out where it was I went still. Maybe you can help?

---

> Having arrived at the start, I was ready to start my journey. I found a vessel, and began.
>
> To start, I let myself drift west as far as I could, which, looking left, allowed a nice view back at where I arrived. Finally I could drift no further and turned north before continuing.
>
> I found myself surrounded, almost as far as the eye could see, by nothing but liquid. This was not what I was after on this adventure, and completely surrounded, I kept on travelling north until I found some sign of life.
>
> The liquid gave way to ice but this allowed me to start fishing for food. I stopped for a bit to catch the fish I was after. By this point, I had drifted east enough to be able to turn around and start heading south.
>
> I came across a isle, quite a long one. At the top, I saw things such as a cottage, and a tiger prowling next to it. Not wanting to be attacked, I kept heading south to see whats further down on this island.
>
> I saw some walkers who seemed to be lying down. Looking up to see what they were gazing at, I saw the night sky, full of galaxies, as well as our own. I believe I saw a planet within our own solar system too.
>
> Leaving this place behind, I started heading north again and come across another isle. This was a lot more chilly, with icebergs and snow. A sunset arrived and as it did, I saw a canary. Rather out of place in this chilly climate, I decided to bring it with me.
>
> Having nearly reached the end of my journey, I came across one final stop. A small place, with another, different looking cottage, and a farmer alongside it.
>
> Finally, I headed south to finish my journey, but stopped off to the east on the way, to quickly thank the owner of my vessel and pay him for my journey. I returned to where I arrived, very content with my adventure, having visited everywhere I could have.

---

## What actually happened?

And, a challenge, **can you draw a map of my journey?**

---

Hint:

> I made this trip in person, and all of you have most likely made many similar trips in your life.

Further hint:

> I travelled maybe around 500m in total. I have made a small edit which is also a hint.

Comment: I think you were rot13(cynlvat n obneq tnzr), but I don't know rot13(juvpu bar).

Comment: @shoover perhaps... perhaps not :P I’m planning first hint in a few hours and it’ll tell you if it’s right path or not :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that this epic voyage was actually:

> A trip to your local **SUPERMARKET**. (Or possibly something smaller like a convenience store, if in the end you have 'visited everywhere [you] could have'...)

*Having arrived at the start, I was ready to start my journey. I found a vessel, and began.*

> You arrived at the entrance to the supermarket and selected a **trolley** or **shopping basket** ('vessel').

*To start, I let myself drift west as far as I could, which, looking left, allowed a nice view back at where I arrived. Finally I could drift no further and turned north before continuing.*

> Turning left inside the shop doors you could look left through the large windows and see the car park. When you reached the end of the shop you turned right up the end aisle.

*I found myself surrounded, almost as far as the eye could see, by nothing but liquid. This was not what I was after on this adventure, and completely surrounded, I kept on travelling north until I found some sign of life.*

> The end aisle in a supermarket is usually where you find all the **alcohol** ('nothing but liquid'). However, on this particular trip you're not shopping for wine, beer or spirits, so you keep on up the end of the aisle.

*The liquid gave way to ice but this allowed me to start fishing for food. I stopped for a bit to catch the fish I was after. By this point, I had drifted east enough to be able to turn around and start heading south.*

> You find yourself at the **fish counter**.  You pick out a fish, move a little along the counter, then turn back south to go back down the next aisle.

*I came across a isle, quite a long one. At the top, I saw things such as a cottage, and a tiger prowling next to it. Not wanting to be attacked, I kept heading south to see whats further down on this island.*

> This aisle ('a isle') is the **bread aisle**. Here you spot products such as *[cottage loaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottage_loaf)* and *[tiger bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_bread)*, but you walk right past them...

*I saw some walkers who seemed to be lying down. Looking up to see what they were gazing at, I saw the night sky, full of galaxies, as well as our own. I believe I saw a planet within our own solar system too.*

> The bread gives way to the **snack section**. Here you see some bags of *[Walkers crisps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkers_(snack_foods))* ('walkers') arranged on the shelves, and above them some chocolate bars - namely, *Galaxy* ('galaxies'), *Milky Way* ('our own') and *Mars bars* ('a planet within our own solar system').

*Leaving this place behind, I started heading north again and come across another isle. This was a lot more chilly, with icebergs and snow. A sunset arrived and as it did, I saw a canary. Rather out of place in this chilly climate, I decided to bring it with me.*

> You leave this aisle and enter the **fruit & veg section**, where you see *iceberg* lettuces, [*snow* peas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_pea), [*sunset* apples](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunset_(apple)) and a [*canary* melon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_melon). Needing one of the melons for tonight's dessert, you pick one up and put it in your trolley.

*Having nearly reached the end of my journey, I came across one final stop. A small place, with another, different looking cottage, and a farmer alongside it.*

> This is the **dairy section**, where the 'cottage' could be *cottage cheese* and the 'farmer' could be *[farmer cheese](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farmer_cheese)*. (Perhaps you need milk for a nice white sauce...)

*Finally, I headed south to finish my journey, but stopped off to the east on the way, to quickly thank the owner of my vessel and pay him for my journey. I returned to where I arrived, very content with my adventure, having visited everywhere I could have.*

> Your final stop en route to the exit is the checkout counter or till, and you pay for your purchases. You leave the shop after a successful shopping trip and looking forward to getting home and into the kitchen to get that dinner cooked!

A map of your expedition would then look something like this:

> [image]

Comment: Congrats! You have correctly identified my journey! The only thing that’s wrong is the frozen food section, in which all of the icebergs, sunset, snow and can at all are foods as well, you may be able to figure out what section they fall under based on what’s missing in the store so far. Your map is spot on too! Well done!! :) I think the only other things are ‘a isle’ and farmers cheese

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Aha, I was closer than I thought then! Have picked up the remaining pieces and think I have the correct area for the 'chilly' section.

Comment: Correct section! But only iceberg is correct :P the chillis wasn’t actually intended but that works quite nicely too lol. There are four fruits mentioned in this section and all 4 are the same format as the iceberg, tiger, cottage clues, where it’s a type of food. See if you can work out what fruits and veg types are mentioned and a tick will be on the way :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Got it. Hopefully the ones in the list are now the ones you were after, or at least in the right ballpark :)

Comment: close enough! I’ll give you the only incorrect one, I was looking for sunset apples :) congrats!! Well deserved tick

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ok, fixed! That's a variety I wasn't aware of - though as there always seem to be THOUSANDS of different ones whenever I shop maybe that's to be expected :) Thanks for the mental runaround! Hungry now for some reason...

Comment: honestly, I was expecting you to solve this from that start, you’re too good at these!! :P go get yourself a well early snack lol!